# How to use JavaScript to ask input from User and assign it to values of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Hi i use this code to view multiple URLs in an `iframe`, now i want to make a script in JavaScript which will ask from user to input urls and will assign URLs in arrays in the below code.

```js
var array = ["https://www.google.com", "https://codepen.io/", "https://www.amazon.in", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

var cnt = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
  $('iframe').attr('src', array[cnt]);
  cnt++;
  if (cnt == array.length) {
    cnt = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="submit">Next Iframe</button>
<iframe></iframe>
```

Comment: Your logic appears to be working fine. However, most sites disallow them selves to be shown within an iframe. In fact, you can see the error when you try and set Google in the frame: `Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=HpxoWdWkIZD38AeJib9Y' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` There is no workaround for this, and that's a good thing for security reasons.

Comment: actually i am not using these urls i am using urls which are on other sever owned by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code

```js
var array = ["https://www.google.com", "https://codepen.io/", "https://www.amazon.in", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

var cnt = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
  $('iframe').attr('src', array[cnt]);
  cnt++;
  if (cnt == array.length) {
    cnt = 0;
  }
});

function addtoArrayFunc(){

var inputVal = $("#inputBox").val();
array.push(inputVal);

}
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="submit">Next Iframe</button>
<iframe></iframe>
<br>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter the URL" id="inputBox">
<button onClick="addtoArrayFunc()">Add to array</button>
```

Comment: i am new to js, can you please tell me how can i use id of input field instead of input tag in var inputVal = $("#inputBox").val(); actually there are many input field in the page which i am modifying

Answer (score 0):

Create a form, and an input. Then read input when user clicks on button/interact in some other way.

```js
   
  var array = ["https://www.google.com", "https://codepen.io/", "https://www.amazon.in", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"];

var cnt = 0;
$('button').click(function() {
  var userurl = $('input').val();
  $('iframe').attr('src', array[cnt] = userurl);
  cnt++;
  if (cnt == array.length) {
    cnt = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
iframe {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<iframe></iframe>
<!-- don't reload page on -->
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
<label> Get URL 
<input type="text"></input>
</label>
<button type="submit">Go
</button>
</form>
```